# Alfresco : Datasource dependency randomly loaded on the objectFinder

Tags: forms, yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've got a problem on a Webscript in Alfresco Share. I changed the blog modification page to add the category picker. The problem is that, sometimes the picker appears, sometimes not...And nothing changed on the the initial data.

So, I pursued my debug plan and found that when the picker doesnt appears it's because the onready function is not called in the objectFinder. I looked deeper in the code to find that finally, the Alfresco Component Base doesn't call the onready function because he doesn't have all the dependecies loaded (The YUI Component have to normally load them) and especialy the Datasource component dependency (YAHOO.Util.Datasource if I remember correctly).

It never appears on Chrome but it appears in IE and Firefox. I looked on the other pages that use ObjectFinder, it's the only page where I encountered this problem. In the other pages, ObjectFinder is used in a pop-up and attached directly to the pop-up. On the page where the problem occurs, ObjectFinder is generated independently and is never attached to the page. Does anyone has an idea or something that could guide me in my researches ? In the worst case, I will create my own component (lighter) just for this page.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked deeply in files such as association.ftl, picker.inc.ftl and object-finder.js files for generating items?